# Do the rules of "tircha detzibbur" apply to the reading of Nesi'im during the beginning of Nissan?

Tags: torah-reading, nissan, tircha-detzibur

Some congregations have a minhag of reading a section from parshat *Nasso* at the beginning of the month of Nssan. The section read is related to the offerings that each tribal leader gave to the dedication of the *mishkan*. Some congregations read this section from a Torah.

I know that there is a rule of *tircha detzibbur* regarding congregational Torah reading. I.e. - we try to avoid or mitigate a pause for the congregation by verifying that the Torah scrolls are rolled to the right place. This explains why this Shabbat, we use 3 Sifrei Torah.

For those shuls that make a congregational reading from *Nasso*, as described above (usually, this is done at the end of davening), do they need a 4th Sefer Torah to avoid "tircha detzibur", or does it not apply in this case, and they can roll one of the 3 (sounds like the 2nd one which ws read from Pinchas would make the most sense) used in the morning service?

Comment: Does the Shul have a fourth Sefer Torah? Does it not? If it does not there is no question what has to be done. If it does there is also no question.

Comment: @GershonGold - If it doesn't have a 4th, that's obvious - there's no choice. So, logically, I'm asking that if it DID have a 4th, and say they didn't want to alter it, b/c it's set for Shabbat mincha, can they reuse one of the others?

Comment: Why can't they use the one from the morning first reading for Shabbos Mincha?

Comment: Are the congregants required to stay? How can there be Tirch deTzibbura if anyone who wants to can just leave?